# No lock button in Status Bar of Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, lock

No lock button is present in the drop down of the status bar in Ubuntu 18.04.

When I go to Settings> Privacy> Screen Lock,
I can click Screen Lock to open the Screen Lock window. In the Screen Lock window "Automatic Screen Lock" is dimmed.

Answer (score 1):

Resetting the desktop theme restored the lock button.

```
dconf reset -f /
```

[OMG Ubuntu: The Secret Command to Reset Ubuntu Desktop to Default Settings](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/10/how-to-reset-ubuntu-desktop-to-default)

Comment: That's not resetting only the "desktop theme", that wipes out the entire bunch of your preferences for the entire desktop and throughout _a lot_ of apps. You will need to redo then all those configuration / preferences / app settings dance in all of them.

Answer (score 0):

`$ dconf reset -f /` or `$ sudo service lightdm restart`

For more key words related `dconf` command run : `$ man dconf`